# How to change the facility of sshd

Tags: rhel, sshd, rsyslog

The default config in **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** is
`#SyslogFacility AUTH`

I added
`SyslogFacility LOCAL5`
below, and `local5.*    /var/log/sshd.log` in **/etc/rsyslog.conf**

As usual restarted **sshd** and **rsyslog.service**

But messages still went to auth.log and sshd.log was not created.